# Android application to transfer files via wireless without using 3rd party cloud tools

Tags: android, windows-7, file-synchronization, wifi

I am looking for an app that will allow me to transfer files from my Android device via the wireless connection. This device is used in a business setting to take pictures. At a later point these pictures are transferred to a workstation. Currently this means that I can do one of the following

- Find the device's cable, plug it into the machine and device, navigate to the storage location on the device, click/drag images to the workstation
- Utilize [Samba](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba&hl=en) shares on the device to manage this wirelessly. Still requires navigation to storage location to transfer data. Also requires root access, which voids my warranty. It also requires that IT (or someone else with experience) set up network shares that all users can access.
- Utilize bluetooth. Not an option as the workstation doesn't have a bluetooth connection

Ideally, this tool will allow me to select files to transfer and they will go to a predefined location on the workstation. I won't have to select the "save to" location each time. I do not want to utilize Dropbox/Google Drive/other cloud service due to the business nature of these images. It does not need to operate over the cellular network. I'd also prefer not to manage network shares for all workstations.

Other requirements:

- A daemon running on the workstation is acceptable, as long as it is not utilizing a third party storage location (Dropbox/Box/Google Drive)
- Can transfer any type of file from device to PC
- I'd prefer not to have open shares on the network if at all possible
- Operates on wireless (non-cellular) network
- No need to navigate to save to location each time data is transferred
- Data does not need to transfer to workstation automatically. A process to bulk select files is acceptable. If an automatic transfer occurs, need the ability to filter what does and does not get transferred (ie. all files generated by the device do not need to end up on the workstation)

The workstation is running Windows 7 with plans to upgrade to Windows 10 at some point in the future. The Android device is running 4.4.4 but will be upgraded to Lollipop "soon". As this will be a business solution, I expect this will not be a free application on the Play Store. That is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend **[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite)** for that. In order to fulfill your requirements, there's a one time setup – and then just "let it do its job":

1. Configure an "Account". *FolderSync* understands a bunch of protocols; for your case, Samba/CIFS should do fine. So you create an "account" with the credentials to be used on the Windows machine the files should go to (machine name/IP, user, password)
2. Configure a "folder pair". This will most likely be the `DCIM/` folder on your Android device, and the place on the PC where the files should go. You can set it up for "unidirectional" (i.e. only copy from device to PC) or "bidirectional" (keep both ends in sync – useful if you e.g. want the "old files" automatically deleted from the Android device once you've deleted/moved them from the "target directory". Optionally set it to auto-sync whenever e.g. your WiFi is connected.

That's it. Now take your photos. As soon as your device connects to your WiFi, they get synced to your PC (or, if you didn't configure that, you'll simply have to trigger it manually).

[image: FolderSync Main] [image: FolderSync Services] [image: Folder pairs] [image: Sync Status]
<sup>*FolderSync* Screenshots (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Using the [paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) gives you even more advantages, e.g. *Tasker* integration – which is the way I use this app (letting *Tasker* decide what should be synced and when).

**Big Pros, matching your requirements:**

- Having it set up once, no further manual work is required. *FolderSync* works reliably (I'm already using it for years – just not with Windows and CIFS, but with Linux and SSH) in different configurations.
- Works via WiFi and mobile data as well – but of course you can tell it e.g. not to use mobile data
- no third-parties involved (you sync directly with your machine). Though if you wish, a bunch of cloud services is directly supported as well (see second screenshot).
- file types don't matter – it syncs everything.
- no need for "open shares" (in terms of "public") – it can negotiate credentials. As long as you're fine with syncing only when "inside", it neither requires "open ports" in your firewall.
- works wirelessly, yes.
- As written: once setup, no more need to "navigate folders" (and you can tell it to "include sub-folders" if you wish so)
- filters are possible AFAIR (I've never used any, so I'm not 100% sure how far this goes)
- automated and manual operation possible

As you already wrote to not expect the app being free: I really recommend the paid version (less than EUR 3 currently). For a business, the price is almost ignorable – a tram ticket is most likely more expensive, a beer at the pub definitely :)

For some alternatives, please see my list about [Syncing files with your own hardware](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync#group_166).

Answer (score 0):

[Send Anywhere (File Transfer)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estmob.android.sendanywhere)

A cross-platform file sharing service which allows users to easily share digital content peer-to-peer, in real-time, without cloud storage.
Unlike messenger or cloud based storage apps Send Anywhere allows the end user to send as many files, of any file type and size, as many times as they want, across Android, iOS, and Desktop. Send Anywhere utilizes p2p networking to bypass cloud storage thereby making the transfer process more secure and quicker. Furthermore, Send Anywhere requires no login or registration - all that is needed is a one time six digit code that will sync the sending and receiving device.
This simple, unlimited, instant file transferring app will make file sharing easier than ever before!
No signup or login required—all you need is a 6-digit key to pair devices.
Share any file type (photos, apps, videos, etc.), of any size, across all mobile devices (Android, iPhone, iPad, iPod) and PC (https://send-anywhere.com)

How it works

Sending

1. Select a file and click “Send”
2. This will generate a 6-digit one time key which you will share with the person you want to send the file to.
3. Stand by.
   Tip: You can also send a push alert to one of the nearby/recently used devices in the list.

Receiving

1. Enter the 6-digit one time key on the receiving device.
2. Enjoy!

Remotely manage your PC files

With the My Devices release, you can remotely manage every Windows and Android device that you’ve registered with Send Anywhere. This means you can access files downloaded on your Windows computer from your Android phone as well as send those files to another device. This seamless process further simplifies your file transferring needs.

More Tips

1. Share as many of your full resolution vacation photos as you want!
2. Be wary of your cellular data usage when moving lots of large files.
3. Share interesting Android apps with your friends!, If you are an app developer, you will love this. It's so easy to share and install .apk files across your test devices.
4. You can choose to upload files for 24hrs.